# How can i replace when its comes True?

Tags: python, list, replace

Code:

```
    list1 = ['peter', 'james', 'code', 'key', 'jack']
    list2 = ['flower', 'john', 'rose', 'red', 'green', 'peter']

f = any([item in list1 for item in list2])

output :  ['Peter', 'james', 'code', 'key', 'jack']
```

when f its True, how can i replace list1 'peter' to 'Peter' when its False nothing to do

Comment: Please add the expected output of your code to the question description.

Comment: Do you want to replace all elements in `list1` with the titlecase or just the overlapping elements?

Comment: `[item.title() if item in list1 else item for item in list2]`

Comment: Just the overlapped elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested you may just write

```
[item.title() if item in list1 else item for item in list2]
```

and obtain as output :

```
['flower', 'john', 'rose', 'red', 'green', 'Peter']
```